# El valor de un vector no cambia al editarlo

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando en una prueba simple con algoritmos de ordenamiento, para ello estoy creando un vector con valores aleatorios con el siguiente codigo:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector(10);
    int arrayLen = sizeof(myVector) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
        myVector[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
}
```

Como se ve en la imagen, intento crear un vector con 10 datos en su interior, pero a la hora de mostrarlo en pantalla ocurre lo siguiente:

1. en lugar de mostrar 10 datos, muestra solo 6
2. en a pesar de tener los datos de forma aleatoria, siempre que vuelvo a ejecutar el programa me muestra los mismos numeros, siendo estos `2,8,5,1,10,5,`

Cabe resaltar que estoy utiliuzando **Visual Studio Code** por si hay algun bug del que no me haya percatado.

el codigo completo es el siguiente por si quieren probar algo:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void PrintArray(std::vector<int> array, const char* state) {
    std::cout << state;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(int); i++) {
        std::cout << array[i];
        std::cout << ",";
    }
}

// this algorithm have a complexity value of (O^n2) because it iters 2 times based on the input of the function (dual for loop)
std::vector<int> SelectionSort(std::vector<int> array) {
    int arrayLen = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    std::vector<int> result(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLen; j++) {
            if (result[i] <= result[j]) {
                std::swap(result[i], result[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// this algorithm have a complexity value of (O^n2) because it iters 2 times based on the input of the function (dual for loop)
std::vector<int> BubbleSort(std::vector<int> array) {
    std::vector<int> result(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < ((sizeof(array) / sizeof(int))); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ((sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)) -1); j++) {
            if (result[j] > result[j+1]) {
                std::swap(result[j], result[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector(10);
    int arrayLen = sizeof(myVector) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
        myVector[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    PrintArray(myVector, "unsorted array:");
    PrintArray(SelectionSort(myVector),"\nSelection Sort:");
    PrintArray(BubbleSort(myVector),"\nBubble Sort   :");

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `en lugar de mostrar 10 datos, muestra solo 6`

Esto:

```
int arrayLen = sizeof(myVector) / sizeof(int);
```

está mal. Esa no es la forma de obtener el número de elementos de un `vector`. Tienes que llamar a su método `size( )`:

- `A pesar de tener los datos de forma aleatoria, siempre que vuelvo a ejecutar el programa me muestra los mismos números`

Eso es por la forma en la que trabaja `rand( )`. Se basa en una *semilla* interna, un valor numérico ... que **siempre es el mismo** cada vez que inicias tu programa.

Para alterar ese valor, hay que usar `srand( )`, que admite un número como nueva *semilla*. Y una buena opción a usar es la fecha/hora actuales, en segundos. Y la función `time( )` nos devuelve justamente eso.

Tu código, corregido:

```
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myVector(10);

    srand(time(nullptr));

    for (int i = 0; i < myVector.size( ); i++) {
        myVector[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Graciaaas, en efecto ese era el problema, muchas gracias!!!